# Issue building cx_Oracle - libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found

Tags: python, oracle, build, cx-oracle

I'm trying to build cx_Oracle for a Python 2.7.2 and Oracle 11g installation but the built cx_Oracle.so cannot find libclntsh.so.11.1 so importing cx_Oracle in Python fails.

```
/mypath/cx_Oracle-5.1.1/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g]$ ldd cx_Oracle.so
    libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002ae9be290000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002ae9be4ab000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000389b600000)
```

I have **libclntsh.so.11.1** in my Oracle client installation directory:

```
/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/lib]$ ls -l libclntsh.so*
libclntsh.so -> /apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
libclntsh.so.11.1
```

And the cx_Oracle setup.py is picking this lib dir up:

```
/mypath/cx_Oracle-5.1.1]$ python2.7 setup.py build
/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/
running build
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/rdbms/demo -I/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/rdbms/public -I/apps/bweb/python-2.7.2/include/python2.7 -c cx_Oracle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -DBUILD_VERSION=5.1.1
In file included from /apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/rdbms/public/oci.h:3024,
                 from cx_Oracle.c:10:
/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/rdbms/public/ociap.h:10788: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/rdbms/public/ociap.h:10794: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -L/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/lib -lclntsh -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.so
```

Is something obviously wrong with this setup?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

My **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** contains the lib directory above with **libclntsh.so.11.1**

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/lib
```

This doesn't seem to make any difference.  I rebuild the cx_Oracle.so file and it still shows `libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found` when I run `$ ldd cx_Oracle.so`.

**Python failing to load the built module:**

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jan 19 2012, 14:38:32)
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**SOLVED**

The issue was related to the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable.  Due to restrictions on the setup I'm working with (corp env) I had to build cx_Oracle as another user (system account).  i.e. I was running this:

```
$ sudo -u username python27 setup.py build
```

So even though **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** was set correctly for me, my version wasn't used when command was executed as a different user.  I was able to build successfully by moving the source code to a location where I had permissions and running the build as my user.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add `/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/lib/` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable
execute the command below in the terminal before running python or add it into your `.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/lib/
```

Comment: which OS are you using? Some UNIX distributions use `LD_LIB_PATH` rather than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? You might also want to check the permissions on the file and make sure it's readable by your script.

Comment: RHEL 6.  I think LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correct, but it seems it's not being taken into consideration when the build of cx_Oracle happens for some reason.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this and it doesn't seem to resolve. I've set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and built cx_Oracle.so again. Still shows libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found. Confirmed it's set in Python interpreter, and am unable to load cx_Oracle due to the above issue. The problem is at the point of building cx_Oracle, correct?

`os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']`
`'/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/lib`
`>>> import cx_Oracle Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`ImportError: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I noticed that in the comment just above, os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] is '/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/lib', whereas in the rest of the question the shared library appears to be in /apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/lib/. Make sure you are pointing to the right directory.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I made a typo in my comment above whilst trying to format correctly with Markdown.  It was pointing to the correct location.  I've found the issue now - I'll update my question with the solution and accept this answer as it was the fundamental issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You forgot to tell your loader cache tool that it needs to look in that directory for libraries. Add that directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or a similar file and run `ldconfig`.

Comment: Thanks.  I've already set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** to include this lib directory - would this achieve the same thing?  I can't edit /etc/ld.so.conf or similar as do not have privileges.

Comment: For now, but you *really* should talk to the sysadmin.

Comment: On Fedora 20, LD_LIBRARY_PATH didn't cut it for me, but /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ worked: echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf; ldconfig

Answer (score 0):

Many oracle products install oraenv. It will set, among other environment variables, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so consider running `. oraenv` instead of setting your environment manually.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **LD_RUN_PATH**. ( LD_RUN_PATH is used by the linker to specify where to look for libraries only at run time.)

Now build cx_Oracle.

```
/mypath/cx_Oracle-5.1.1]$ export LD_RUN_PATH="/apps/oracle/client/11.2.0.1/home1/lib"
/mypath/cx_Oracle-5.1.1]$ python2.7 setup.py build
```

This will not require the setting of LD_LIBRARY_PATH while importing cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this here so no one else might waste time with what i did wrong.

So you also have to MAKE SURE you reinstall/isntall cx_ORacle AFTER you install the oracle isntant client -I wasted some time before i tried it  and it worked like a charm.
My set up was cx_ORacle8 and oracle client 18.5.
Also need to export ld library path every time before you run the python script as its (18.5)

Comment: All recent versions of cx_Oracle do not need to have Oracle Client libraries or header files available during installation of the pre-built binary wheel packages, or even if compiling from source code.  At run time only the Oracle Client libraries are needed - Oracle headers are never needed.  Finally, try the most recent version of cx_Oracle because it doesn't necessarily need Oracle Client libraries at runtime.  Install with `python -m pip install oracledb` See the [release announcement](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: I see , in my case i had to use a bit old version because i was not sure  if there were any version dependencies so i just  tried to get the one i had to work with what i had.
Then again its is just one of the scenario i guess.