# Linux profile.d environment variables don't work with cx_oracle in Python

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, cx-oracle

This is a bit of a continuation from my previous question: [cx_Oracle does not recognize location of Oracle software installation for installation on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928203/cx-oracle-does-not-recognize-location-of-oracle-software-installation-for-instal).

After I was able to get cx_oracle installed properly, I wanted to set up my environment so the environment variables don't have to be exported every time.

To do this, I wrote a shellscript that included these two export statements:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/user1/instantclient_12_1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
```

And saved this .sh file into the `/etc/profile.d/` folder.

When I log into the server again with PuTTY, the echo statements say that the environment variables are there:

```
# echo $ORACLE_HOME
/home/user1/instantclient_12_1
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/home/user1/instantclient_12_1
```

But when I run some python code with cx_oracle, I get an error:

```
ImportError: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The code only runs again when I re-enter the export commands for the environment variables.  After I do that, the code using cx_oracle runs fine.

Why don't the environment variables work properly even though they show up when I do the echo command?  And how do I get the environment variables to persist properly?

The guides I read say to do it with a shell script in `/etc/profile.d/` because it's better to not edit `/etc/profile` directly.

**Update:**

I tried adding the two export lines to `/etc/profile`, but I still get the same problem where the environment variables are there when I echo, but I still get this error when trying to use cx_oracle in python:

```
ImportError: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing some key thing about defining environment variables?

**Second Update:**
I tried initializing the environment with a shell script that I planned to run with the code that calls cx_Oracle:

Contents of StartServer.sh:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/user1/instantclient_12_1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
python3 ./UDPDBQuery.pyc
```

And I try to run the code in the background by doing:

```
bash StartServer.sh &
```

But I still run into that same error as before, as if I did not put in the environment variables.  It only works if I export the variables myself, and then run the code again.  The code also stops running in the background when I log out.  I'm still very confused as to why it isn't working.

Are environment variables not usable by cx_oracle unless I manually do the export statement for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found out that one of the two environment variables was not exporting properly with the `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d`, and doing `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would give me `No such file or directorytclient_12_1`, but `$ORACLE_HOME` would give me `/home/user1/instantclient_12_1/: is a directory`.

The way I solved this was to split the export statements into two separate shell scripts in `profile.d`.

Everything works now.

Comment: Your answer helped me realize something was wrong with LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my case. I got more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654090/issue-building-cx-oracle-libclntsh-so-11-1-not-found