# Does the pip option "--force-reinstall" recompiles a module? (I'm trying to reinstall cx_Oracle)

Tags: python, pip, cx-oracle

My setup has:

```
- oracle-instantclient (downgraded from 12 to 11)
- Virtual Environment with Python + Django + cx_Oracle
```

When I downgraded the oracle-instantclient, I tried to reinstall cx_oracle using:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall cx_Oracle
```

The problem is that cx_Oracle keeps complaining that I'm not using the previous installed version 12:

```
$ python -c "import cx_Oracle"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, some questions here: "--force-reinstall" is not supposed to make a full reinstall, including a module recompile (aka cx_Oracle)? Somebody has some suggestion about how to workaround this issue? I looked at the [pip manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=--force-reinstall) and just tells me that it reinstalls the package. Not very useful.

## Update1:

I tried to follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654090/issue-building-cx-oracle-libclntsh-so-11-1-not-found), adding my cx_Oracle path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it's still not working.

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/home/myuser/myuserenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle-5.2.1.dist-info
```

Note that my root user has a different python while my virtualenv uses its own python installation.

```
[root@myserver]# which python
/usr/bin/python
```

From my virtual environment:

```
(myvirtualenv) [myuser@myserver]$ which python
~/myvirtualenv/bin/python
```

Is there some way of installing cx_Oracle manually using my root user but putting the files at the virtual environment somehow?

## Update2:

I tried to download cx_Oracle and compile manually using the following command:

```
sudo -u myuser ~/myvirtualenv/bin/python setup.py build install
```

But now I'm seeing some permission errors:

```
(...)
error: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg': Permission denied
```

Am I doing the right thing? I don't want to mess this environment. Thanks.

Comment: No, reinstalling won't help. Add path to cx_Oracle libs to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654090/issue-building-cx-oracle-libclntsh-so-11-1-not-found

Comment: Hum... I tried but didn't work... I exported my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add the ...[myvirtualenv]/lib/python3.5/site-packages and /lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle-5.2.1.dist-info, but still having the same error... Some other suggestion?

Comment: Please note that I can use sqlplus without any problem, so it's a problem just with cx_Oracle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question (although you seem to have had another problem) is as follows:
It depends on the module's structure. If its setup script calls the compiler, then yes it does. Because, you see, pip modules by default do not include compiled parts, it's up to the module author to provide them.

Comment: Hum... Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks Feakuru.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally install. The problem is that I had to use the python of my [virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979513/python-manually-install-package-using-virtualenv). A simple solution but that I completely missed.

Steps:

```
pip download cx_Oracle
tar -xvf cx_Oracle-5.2.1.tar.gz
~/myenv/bin/python setup.py -v build
sudo ~/myenv/bin/python setup.py install
```

Note that I had to use sudo in the last step. Without this I was having this permission error:

```
error: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg': Permission denied
```